# Task output encoding in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm learning BeautifullSoup with Visual Studio Code and when I run this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'user-agent':ua.chrome}
google_page = requests.get('https://www.google.com',headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(google_page.content,'lxml') # html.parser

print(soup.prettify())
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\ ... \intro-to-soup-2.py", line 13, in 
>       print(soup.prettify())   File "C:\ ... \Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
>   line 19, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character
>   '\U0001f440' in position 515: character maps to

If I force the encoding for utf-8 in the soup variable I won't be abble to use prettify as it doesn't work with strings...
Also tried using # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on the first line of code without sucess.

Here is my tasks.json for this project:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "python",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["${file}"],
"files.encoding": "utf8",
// Controls after how many characters the editor will wrap to the next line. Setting this to 0 turns on viewport width wrapping (word wrapping). Setting this to -1 forces the editor to never wrap.
"editor.wrappingColumn": 0, // default value is 300
// Controls the font family.
"editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Malgun Gothic', '맑은 고딕','Courier New', monospace",
// Controls the font size.
"editor.fontSize": 15,
"showOutput": "always"
}
```

The exact same code is running in PyCharm without any problems.
Any ideas how I can fix this in Visual Studio Code?

Here's my "pip freeze" result:

```
astroid==1.5.3
beautifulsoup4==4.5.3
colorama==0.3.9
fake-useragent==0.1.7
html5lib==0.999999999
isort==4.2.15
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
lxml==3.7.2
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==1.7.1
requests==2.12.5
selenium==3.4.3
six==1.10.0
webencodings==0.5
wrapt==1.10.10
xlrd==1.0.0
XlsxWriter==0.9.6
```

Thank you for your time,

Eunito.

Comment: Are pycharm and VScode running the same install of python?

Comment: How can I see which version I'm using in VSCode? I instaled PyCharm today so I assume it is using the latest there

Comment: @Eunito Run this as a script in VSCode: `import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))`. Also, pycharm might be using any install you have (if you have muliple installations) so downloading it recently does not assure that it runs the latest python.

Comment: Ran that on pycharm and VSC and the output was Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: **edit** - just updated python to the latest version and the problem keeps happening:(

Comment: Can you split the prettify and the print and also include the full trace?

Comment: Also where does the output of this tasks.json business go? What happens in VSCode when you right click the editor window and just say 'Run Python file in Terminal'? I think this has something to do with where you're trying to output to and not really related to BS4. It looks like it's choking on converting an emoji to cp1252. This doesn't happen in the PyCharm console because the PyCharm console is unicode aware. The VSCode one should be too, though.

Comment: @pvg - in the terminal all is running fine :/ how can I force VSC to use the right version if this is the case?

Comment: Well, what is this output going to? The standard windows console? Do you really need to be printing giant piles of html with emoji to the console?

Comment: This happens even if I try to find a specific div content...

Comment: **edit** This problem happens even if I try to find a specific div content... I just would like to fix this so when I click Ctrl+Shift+B it shows the correct output without the need to use the right button and run in terminal... :/ if that isn´t possible I'll have to stick with that! eheheh

Comment: I filed this as a bug in VSCode, you can track what happens to it here. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/29358

Comment: Thank you for your help and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here seems to be the encoding the python interpreter believes stdout/stderr support. For some reason (arguably, a bug in VSCode) this is set to some platform-specific value (cp1252 in windows for you, I was able to reproduce the issue on OS X and got ascii) instead of utf-8 which the VSCode output window supports. You can modify your task.json to look something like this to address this - it sets an environment variable forcing the Python interpreter to use utf8 for output.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "python3",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["${file}"],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "options": {
        "env": {
            "PYTHONIOENCODING":"utf-8"
        }
    }
}
```

The relevant bit is the "options" dictionary.

Comment: you sir are A GOD! Thank you!

Comment: how to set cpp encoding?