# Problem Python UnicodeEncode Error: Cannot decode

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert the byte data b'\u1eb9' back to a utf-8 character but failed.
Why i can encode a unicode character to a byte data but cannot reverse the process?
[image]

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Code? If so, this may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724461

Comment: I use Sublime Text, but after that i tried this code on VS and it work so i think the system build of sublime text lack something. I add the "env": { 'PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8" } and it work.

Comment: You may try [this post's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24242596/5223223).

Answer (score 0):

I use Sublime Text, but after that i tried this code on VS and it work so i think the system build of sublime text lack something. I add the "env": { 'PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8" } and it work.